# jvisualvm in Unix

Tags: java, unix, jvm, jvisualvm

We started to check the performance of my application as its getting slow after some time. I am using jvisualvm to observe the cause. Can anyone tell how can i use jvisualvm in Unix as in Windows we can check it through UI. Can we have the same view in Unix also.

Lets my path to jvisualvm is /Prj/tools/java/bin/jvisualvm

When i use help,

```
Usage: /Prj/tools/java/bin/../lib/visualvm//platform7/lib/nbexec {options} arguments  

General options:  
  --help                show this help  
  --jdkhome <path>      path to Java(TM) 2 SDK, Standard Edition  
  -J<jvm_option>        pass <jvm_option> to JVM  

  --cp:p <classpath>    prepend <classpath> to classpath  
  --cp:a <classpath>    append <classpath> to classpath  
Core options:  
  --laf <LaF classname> use given LookAndFeel class instead of the default  
  --fontsize <size>     set the base font size of the user interface, in points  
  --locale <language[:country[:variant]]> use specified locale  
  --userdir <path>      use specified directory to store user settings  

Module reload options:  
  --reload /path/to/module.jar  Installs or reinstalls a module JAR file.
```

Comment: just use that binary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VisualVM over Putty SSH-tunnel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314092/visualvm-over-putty-ssh-tunnel)

Comment: did u find how to run it ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use Mobaxterm tool to connect to Linux box.
2. set display variable as:
     setenv DISPLAY :0.0
3. go to /bin
4. Launch as: ./jvisualvm

I hope this works

Answer (score 1):

Just type in your terminal:

```
/Prj/tools/java/bin/jvisualvm
```

And hit enter. If you want to pass some arguments or options (like JDK home) put it after "jvisualvm" in the command above using the format provided by help.

Comment: I am already in JDK bin directory and if If use command like :  [server-name bin]$/Prj/tools/java/bin/jvisualvm &enter. It stops for 3-4 sec then nothing happens. prompt comes to next line

Comment: do you have JAVA_HOME set up? what does "echo $JAVA_HOME" print?

Comment: Earlier It was not set, Now I set and after echo $JAVA_HOME it prints /Prj/tools/java . But still same internal error.

Comment: @Champ23 wait, are you doing it remotely? if so then how are you connecting to the server?

Comment: Yes, Remotely. I am trying to access server through putty.

Comment: @Champ23 and are you running it with X Forwarding?

Comment: We connect through VPN and then Using remote desktop we do task.About X forwarding i don't know as the setup is given by client

Comment: @Champ23 remote desktop? so you can use other GUI applications there? it's not only a bare terminal (command line)? I though (still think) it's something with how X server is configured at the Unix machine

Comment: Yes X forwarding, as in error i can see it on Linux. Yes through VPN we have access on remote desktop to access UI of application  and Linux server through puyty.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the remote connectivity to the unix box from the `jvisualvm`.

Else, you can set the `DISPLAY` parameter of the unix to your desktop IP [like `DISPLAY=<your IP>:0.0;export DISPLAY`] 
**Note:** Use the unix command according to your `SHELL`

Comment: I did try but getting below exception: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: Probably the firewall issue... I am not aware how to fix the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Goto the JDK bin folder and run the `jvisualvm` binary by typing `jvisualvm` and pressing enter.

Comment: yes I am using : [server-name bin]$/Prj/tools/java/bin/jvisualvm  &enter. It stops for 3-4 sec then nothing happens. prompt comes to next line.