# Remote monitoring a Tomcat 7 server using VisualVM and SSH

Tags: ssh, tomcat7, jmx, visualvm

Sorry if this is a repeat of a question asked previously, but I have tried out the solutions provided here and elsewhere and none of them seem to work for me.

**Scenario**: I need to profile a production Tomcat 7 server that lives behind a firewall. I only have SSH access to this server. The profiling tool of choice is Visualvm and these servers do not have a GUI installed. Both the server and the machine I am trying to connect from run Ubuntu 10.04 server LTS.

**Possible solution**: Using visualvm over SSH tunnels seem to be possible and the link given below gives a pretty detailed guide to doing this:

[Tomcat+VisualVM+SSH guide](https://www.liferay.com/web/thiago.moreira/blog/-/blogs/how-to-monitor-liferay-tomcat-remotely-through-firewalls-using-visualvm)

Also I have added a jmxremote.access file to the /conf dir in Tomcat with the following two lines:

```
monitorRole readonly
controlRole readwrite
```

**Problem**: I followed the steps provided in the article and everything seems to be fine. I can connect to the jmx ports in the server locally (from the server) using jmxterm and the connection string given in the guide.

I configured local tomcat as per the guide as a test and Visualvm had no problem connecting to this tomcat instance using the connection string.

However, VisualVM will not connect to the remote server over SSH tunnel. I tried JConsole as it it simpler and has better logging facilities and I get the following sequence of messages:

```
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi://localhost:12009/jndi/rmi://localhost:12008/jmxrmi]  connecting...
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi://localhost:12009/jndi/rmi://localhost:12008/jmxrmi] finding stub...
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi://localhost:12009/jndi/rmi://localhost:12008/jmxrmi] connecting stub...
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi://localhost:12009/jndi/rmi://localhost:12008/jmxrmi] getting connection...
FINER: [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector: jmxServiceURL=service:jmx:rmi://localhost:12009/jndi/rmi://localhost:12008/jmxrmi] failed to connect: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
```

Any ideas as to what I've done wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue you are having, which the referenced article does not really address, is the way that jmx-rmi, or more specifically, RMI itself works. Your Tomcat server setup like this:

1. Created an RMI remotable that is configured to connect to **localhost:12009**.
2. Created an RMI registry on localhost with a listening port of **localhost:12008**.

When you run locally, you lookup the stub in the RMI registry, and when you invoke against the stub to issue a jmx call, it connects to **localhost:12009**, no problem.

When you run remotely through SSH, I am assuming you have tunneled from your remote to the tomcat server on port 12008, so when you issue your request, your *remote's* `localhost:12008` is tunneled to `tomcatServer:12008` since the log output seems to indicate that you found the stub ok.

Next, your remote executes against the stub which in turn attempts to connect to `localhost:12009` and fails.

My guess is that you need to tunnel your remote's localhost:12008 *and* localhost:12009 to be redirected to tomcatServer:12008 *and* tomcatServer:12009.

Another way of getting around this is to ditch the RMI jmx protocol and use something like [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/) (HTTP), [JMX-WS](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxnetbeans/entry/j2ee_deployment_of_jmx_ws) (HTTP WebService) or [JMXMP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jmx/overview/connectors.html) (Socket). This will make your SSH tunelling life a lot easier. If you want to try JMXMP, I created a github project called [OpenDMK](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK) which has mavenized builds. You will want the [jmx-optional](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK/tree/master/OpenDMK/jmx-optional) package.

Comment: Nicholas, thank you for the answer. I do have both localhost:12008 and localhost:12009 tunneled to the corresponding ports on the tomcat server. It is just not working. I took your suggestion to try JMXMP and it works magnificently. Thank you.

Comment: You may use standard RMI and SSH tunneling, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609961/visualvm-over-ssh/31185858#31185858

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question! -- I had the same basic need. Sorry, I'm not actually adding anything new here but thought I would mention that the reference you provided:
  https://www.liferay.com/web/thiago.moreira/blog/-/blogs/how-to-monitor-liferay-tomcat-remotely-through-firewalls-using-visualvm
just worked right away for me (with just very minor adjustments only related with more recent versions -- Tomcat 7, and VisualVM 1.3.8). In my case Tomcat is running on CentOS 6.6, and the monitoring machine is a Mac (perhaps this could help somebody else out there).  Thanks again.